# Redirect as response to Ajax request ends up returning empty

Tags: ajax, redirect, primefaces

We are using Primefaces 3M4 and one of our pages has a p:dataTable which uses ajax calls for events:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":newsForm:newsDlg" oncomplete="newsDlg.show();"/>
```

When the session times out the page gets redirected to /login.xhtml which works fine for non-ajax actions (menu items, etc) but when I select a row in the datatable after the session has expired the page doesn't change to the login page and in Firebug I see the following:

**Under dashboard.xhtml Headers section of Firebug**

```
Response Headers
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By    JSF/2.0
Location    http://localhost:8080/RetailerPortal/faces/login.xhtml
Content-Length  0
Date    Fri, 11 Nov 2011 18:32:42 GMT

Request Headers
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
Accept  application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Faces-Request   partial/ajax
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost:8080/RetailerPortal/faces/dashboard.xhtml
Content-Length  389
Cookie  csfcfc=_30Xsr; JSESSIONID=fg1bV1sZkzKIgNtkH0bz0N0f; JSESSIONID=C65BF4EED70299ABFE4B73614118295E
```

**Under dashboard.xhtml Response**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[-3728406524126180805:2441995557020829808]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

**Under dashbaoard.xhtml Post**

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
javax.faces.ViewState   7521050094575005695:7928145831130537413
javax.faces.behavior.even...    rowSelect
javax.faces.partial.ajax    true
javax.faces.partial.event   rowSelect
javax.faces.partial.execu...    newsForm:newsTable
javax.faces.partial.rende...    newsForm:newsDlg
javax.faces.source  newsForm:newsTable
newsForm    newsForm
newsForm:newsTable_instan...    3
newsForm:newsTable_select...    3
Source
newsForm=newsForm&newsForm%3AnewsTable_selection=3&javax.faces.ViewState=7521050094575005695%3A7928145831130537413&javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=newsForm:newsTable&javax.faces.partial.execute=newsForm:newsTable&javax.faces.partial.render=newsForm:newsDlg&javax.faces.behavior.event=rowSelect&javax.faces.partial.event=rowSelect&newsForm:newsTable_instantSelectedRowKey=3
```

**Under login.xhtml's headers**

```
Response Headers
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By    JSF/2.0
Cache-Control   no-cache
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=MdhyizD+8IkuFvLZD+6jWlUz; Path=/RetailerPortal
Content-Type    text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length  196
Date    Fri, 11 Nov 2011 18:32:42 GMT
Request Headers
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
Accept  application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://localhost:8080/RetailerPortal/faces/dashboard.xhtml
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Faces-Request   partial/ajax
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie  csfcfc=_30Xsr; JSESSIONID=fg1bV1sZkzKIgNtkH0bz0N0f; JSESSIONID=C65BF4EED70299ABFE4B73614118295E
```

**Under login.xhtml's XML section**

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{6ccf85cf-5c69-438c-a9bb-e66423a36a48} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

^

**Response code**

```
HttpServletResponse servResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;                  
servResponse.sendRedirect("login.xhtml");
servResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question [in this blog](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.com/2010/10/jsf-ajax-redirect-after-session-timeout.html)

with the relevant code for at the bottom of the blog post in the doRedirect method.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess--

If you're trying to redirect from an ajax response, you can't do that 301/302 style-- you have to send a message back to the browser and have the browser redirect via javascript.

Probably the non-ajax ones are working because they're using 301/302s.